# How to delete file created by me in Android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm saving an image in DCIM directory, but in cases, I need to delete it.
Previously, I called just image.delete(), where image is file. But now this image is saved in another way:

```
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM" + File.separator + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);

    Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
    boolean saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
```

I tried to make a query with its name and call contentResolver.delete(...), but it doesn't work.

I have permission to write external storage, but I don't want to use SAF.

How can I delete such file?

Comment: You can use `android:requestLegacyStorage="true"` in manifest and continue using the old apis for now.

Comment: @DarShan you mean: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `delete` method of `ContentResolver` using the `Uri` you got when you called insert.

```
 Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
 OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
 boolean saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
 ......
 int result = resolver.delete(imageUri, null, null);
 if (result > 0) {
     Log.d("Tag", "File deleted");
 }
```

If you didn't store the Uri you need to perform a `query()`, retrieve the content and then call `delete`.

Comment: For me, this does not work, the file itself is not deleted (I can still see it in a file explorer).

Comment: @user3738870 are you using Android Q? Check my answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62362565/5434346

Comment: @K.Os Thanks but that won't work for me since the problem is not due to a security exception (the file was created by my app so I don't need permission). The file simply stays there even if it's deleted from the `MediaStore`.

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution should include also handling the potential errors which will occure on Andorid Q when trying to delete using ContentResolver. In that case, you should wrap your code in the try/catch block.
Below solution:

```
      try {
        // 1
        getApplication<Application>().contentResolver.delete(
                imageUri,"${MediaStore.Images.Media._ID} = ?",
                arrayOf(imageId)
        )
      }
       // 2
      catch (securityException: SecurityException) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
          val recoverableSecurityException =
                  securityException as? RecoverableSecurityException
                          ?: throw securityException

             val intentSender = recoverableSecurityException.userAction.actionIntent.intentSender
             startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender,
                DELETE_PERMISSION_REQUEST,
                null,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                null
              )
        } else {
          throw securityException
        }
      }
```

1. Here, you call contentResolver.delete() inside a try block since this method can throw a SecurityException at runtime. The method requires the ContentUri of the image you want to delete. In the where parameter, you specify that you want to delete an image based on its _ID. In the final parameter, you pass the string version of the _ID in an array.
2. In Android 10 and above, it isn’t possible to delete or modify items from MediaStore directly. You need permission for these actions. The correct approach is to first catch RecoverableSecurityException, which contains an intentSender that can prompt the user to grant permission. You then startIntentSenderForResult with the intentSender extracted from RecoverableSecurityException to grant the additional permission to delete file on Android Q.

Source: https://www.raywenderlich.com/9577211-scoped-storage-in-android-10-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

intent.addFlags before invoke the method startActivityForResult.
like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
          | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Because it check permission in ContentProvider#enforceWritePermissionInner.

The real implement is in ActivityManagerService#checkPermission method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  File file = new File(delPath);
  if (file.exists()) {
   try {
        Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context,
                        getApplicationContext()
                                .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                int deletefile = contentResolver.delete(imageUri, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Here delete path `delPath` is the file path of Image you want to delete from storage.